# Google Sheets data translated into C++ code?

Tags: c++, excel, spreadsheet

What is the best way to turn Google Sheets or Excel documents into C++ code? This can be done by extracting the document, the data, or in real-time. Basically, I want C++ codes without writing them in C++. There are many ways to make spreadsheets using C++ and I know there are methods to go in the reverse order, I just don't know all of them and which 1 is the best. I would be fine with starting up a C++ program and then writing in a spreadsheet and the C++ program would update its code. But in the end, I just want pure C++ code that reflects the data of the spreadsheet without writing in C++, since I don't have the experience.

Let me just make this clear. I dont want to embed a spreadsheet into a C++ program and I dont want a layered program (like python) that turns code into other code. I want pure C++ code using a spreadsheet. Must be C++ because it has to be fast.

Comment: Understand the logic then write the code...

Comment: C++ is generally logic, not data. What does it mean to transform the data of a spreadsheet into C++ logic? Could you give an example like "if cell A1 in my sheet fizzles twenty schlemies, then the generated C++ program should do... something"

Comment: So let's just talk about using simple functions and numerical data. Let's say in Google sheets I have just 1 cell and it's a randbetween with 1 as min and 10 as max. How do I convert that same program, which uses a function and numbers, C++ without coding in C++?